# Index error when submitting an document to elasticsearch in spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I'm experiencing sporadically issues when submitting documents to an index.

Whats happening is that sometimes i get the following error when i try to submit a document to an index. but if i submit another document right after the second one is submitted successfully with no errors.

I've tried searching all over the web for similar issues, but this looks more like an issue with the dependency, rather than Elasticsearch itself.

The error message is following:

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException: Error while index for request: index {[converterlog_test][_doc][d388d3be-2e9e-4474-a952-e4a6b146487f], 
source[{"logId":"d388d3be-2e9e-4474-a952-e4a6b146487f","date":"2020-02-10T13:32:24.138","output":"Compilation in progress...\nCompilation successful","filename":"CDNORNCNCINT02380","exitCode":0,"maybeError":false}]}
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at no.intility.CdrConverter.Controllers.CdrConverterController.startCdrConverter(CdrConverterController.java:65)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
...
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: 30,000 milliseconds timeout on connection http-outgoing-0 [ACTIVE]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient$SyncResponseListener.get(RestClient.java:944)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.performRequest(RestClient.java:233)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.internalPerformRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:1764)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:1734)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequestAndParseEntity(RestHighLevelClient.java:1696)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.index(RestHighLevelClient.java:928)
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchRestTemplate.index(ElasticsearchRestTemplate.java:694)
    ... 24 more
```

My project uses these following classes/frameworks/dependencies.

Dependency

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Model Class:

```java
@Document(indexName = "#{ configBean.indexName }", type = "_doc")
public class ConverterLog {

    @Id @Field(type = FieldType.Text)
    private String logId;

    @Field(type = FieldType.Date)
    private String date;

    @Field(type = FieldType.Text)
    private String output;

    @Field(type = FieldType.Text)
    private String filename;

    @Field(type = FieldType.Integer)
    private int exitCode;

    @Field(type = FieldType.Boolean)
    private boolean maybeError;

    public ConverterLog(String output, String filename, int exitCode, boolean maybeError) {
        setDate(LocalDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("UTC")).toString());
        setLogId(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        setOutput(output);
        setFilename(filename);
        setExitCode(exitCode);
        setMaybeError(maybeError);
    }

    ... Getters & setters
```

Repository:

```java
public interface ConverterLogRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<ConverterLog, String> {

}
```

Service:

```java
@Service
public class ConverterLogService {

    private ConverterLogRepository converterLogRepository;

    public ConverterLogService(ConverterLogRepository converterLogRepository) {
        this.converterLogRepository = converterLogRepository;
    }

    public ConverterLog submitTerminalOutput(String terminalOutput, String filename, int exitcode, boolean maybeError)  {
        return converterLogRepository.index(new ConverterLog(terminalOutput, filename, exitcode, maybeError));
    }
}
```

Comment: this is a conneciton timeout, can you try increasing this value to more than 30 seconds?

Comment: I just added timeout settings to application.properties
`spring.elasticsearch.rest.connection-timeout=120s
spring.elasticsearch.rest.read-timeout=120s`

I'm still getting a timeout error, 

`Caused by: java.io.IOException: listener timeout after waiting for [90000] ms`

Comment: 90 sec in the error doesn't match the configured 120secs. And it's a different exception on the listener now. How many messages do you send? A repository save always does a refresh after saving, so sending many single inserts might impose some load on the cluster. When you get lots aof data to index, can you collect them to batches?

Comment: I'm only indexing one document at the time, i think that i have narrowed it down to a network issue. That my company has a netscaler that disconnects idle sockets after x amount of time, and the elasticsearch client doesn't get informed that the connection is broken. And then tried to send on the old connection

Comment: looks indeed like some network problem. I'm not sure if we could address this problem from spring data elasticsearch, or if this is something that should be handled by the underlying network libraries.

Comment: Thanks for the help with debugging. Ive not solved this problem totally yet, but i made a small hack that retries to send logs if there is an error. Will keep on trying to fix this later though.